# Why won't embedded PDFs in Word 2010 open on other systems?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, embedding

Embedding PDF documents in Word 2010 results in an error when trying to open them on other systems:

> The server application, source file, or item can't be found, or
>   returned an unknown error. You may need to reinstall the server
>   application.

I've followed the normal for embedding files (and the same procedure that worked for me when using Word 2007). The files aren't set to be `linked to`. I've also uninstalled Acrobat X, which I read might encourage a permissions problem. I have Foxit Reader installed, which the files are associated with locally, although this hasn't caused a problem when used with Word 2007.

Comment: Did you uninstall/replace Acrobat Reader from the computer you're making the Word doc on, or the one you're trying to view the embedded PDF's on?

Comment: Yep - as mentioned above, it's uninstalled. The problem occurs on any computer that the document is opened on, so it's not specific to one particular recipient.